# Use jQuery Validation Engine with Tabs?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-validation-engine

I have an ASP.NET web forms page that uses jQuery UI tabs. Within each tab there are sets of inputs, including a button that submits the inputs within the tab (using an AJAX call, but that's not relevant to this discussion).

I want to attach the jquery validation engine (https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) to only the subset of inputs that comprise the tab contents, however, because of the way ASP.NET web forms works, there is only a single form element and the validation engine must attach to a form.

Is there a simple way to tell this validation engine to include the currently visible tab/elements in the validation call?

Answer (score 2):

Edit to the response:

What you are looking for is even easier!!!  If you simply want to validate fields on the tab the user is currently on without restricting them to go to other tabs, then ignore the tabs beforeActivate part of the code I provided, and initialize your jQuery Validation Engine to **ignore validating non-visible fields** which is what they will be for *all non-active tabs*.  Your code would look like this:

```
jQuery("#myForm").validationEngine('attach', {
    promptPosition: "bottomLeft",
    validationEventTrigger: "submit",
    validateNonVisibleFields: false // this does the trick!
});
```

Here is the new JSFiddle to illustrate the example: http://jsfiddle.net/T7daH/

Cheers! :-)

------------------------------------------------------- Original Answer -----------------------------------------------------

There is actually a pretty straightforward way to implement the jQuery Validation Engine with a form that spans multiple tabs without having to programmatically trigger validation on each field or tab click.

If you have the following form that spans multiple tabs...

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <input type="text" id="requiredFiled" name="requiredField" class="validate[required]" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

Then you set up the form and tabs like this:

```
jQuery("#myForm").validationEngine('attach', {
    promptPosition: "bottomLeft",
    validationEventTrigger: "submit",
    validateNonVisibleFields: true,
    updatePromptsPosition: true
});

$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            if (!$("#myForm").validationEngine('validate')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#myForm').validationEngine('hide');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#myForm").validationEngine('validate');
                }, 450);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The result is that the user cannot select another tab if the tab the user is currently on is not fully valid.  Here is the JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g9yLL/36/

Cheers! :-)

Comment: I appreciate your clear example, but it does not answer my question. To be clear, I want only the current tab to be validated when I click the save button on that tab. I do not want the system to prevent the user from selecting other tabs because the current tab is not valid.

Comment: @Sosiosh -- even easier!  I updated the answer and here is the JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T7daH/

Comment: You are a saint, indeed, but I need to test your piety. ASP.NET has one form per page. I have other input controls (i.e. search box) on that page outside of the tabs. I also have tabs, and each tab has multiple inputs and a button. I want to click the button and only have the inputs within that tab validate. Clicking the button does not "submit" the form, but it does run code, including validation of the current tab's inputs. Also note from my original question: "the validation engine must attach to a form." How do I validate the tab contents but not the search box outside the tabs?

Comment: @Sosish -- As a courtesy to everyone who takes time to answer your questions, it would be nice if you could actually include snippets of your code because nowhere in your initial question do you mention that you have input fields OUTSIDE of your tabs.  The way your original question is phrased, the answer I provided is perfectly valid, but now you are effectively changing the scope of your question.  How about you create a JSFiddle that closely replicates the code you have, and I'll provide the solution so that I don't keep providing answers to wrong questions.  Deal?

Comment: My original question states "I want to attach the jquery validation engine ... to only the subset of inputs that comprise the tab contents." You really don't have to solve my question if you don't want to; although I appreciate your efforts, I will not respond to passive aggressive responses. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a website with a form with multi-tab and solved it using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
$('#tab1').click(function(){
// #tab1  name of the tab / a href link inside that tab 

   var field1 = $("#field1").validationEngine('validate');
   var field2 = $("#field2").validationEngine('validate');  

  if(field1 || sources )
  { // to show the error messages ;
   return false;
  }     
 });


 $('#tab2').click(function(){
// #tab2  name of the tab / a href link inside that tab 

   var field1 = $("#field1").validationEngine('validate');
   var field2 = $("#field2").validationEngine('validate');  

  if(field1 || field2 )
  { // to show the error messages ;
   return false;
  }     
 });

);
```

For more information check https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine and search for field validation under validate heading.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple solution that did not involve maintaining javascript validation code whenever validated inputs are added or removed from the form being validated. I appreciate the suggestion, but having to programmatically trigger validation on each individual field is both complex, and also causes the validation engine to display validation tooltips for each field that does not pass the validation rules. This is not the same behavior as the engine exhibits when validating an entire form at once. Thanks otherwise!

Comment: @Sosiosh, did you ever find a solution to this problem?